# xpath for <img src="/images/banner2.gif" width="488" height="63" border="0" hspace="8" vspace="4">

Tags: eclipse, selenium, xpath, webdriver

What should be the xpath of the below HTML element. This element doesn't have any class locator in the div tag

```
<img src="/images/banner2.gif" width="488" height="63" border="0" hspace="8" vspace="4">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not mandatory that you can use only `class` or `id` attribute.You can use other attribute as well to make your element uniquely identify.Here you can use `src` attribute.

Try **xpath**:

```
//img[@src='/images/banner2.gif']
```

**Java Code:**

```
WebElement image = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[@src='/images/banner2.gif']"));
```

Comment: The above solution worked for me .. thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
                    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@src='/images/banner2.gif']")))
```

or

```
   WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
                        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "img")))
```

**Note:** add below imports to your solution ::

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```